# Cannot import colors from Adobe Illustrator ai-file to Inkscape

Tags: import, adobe, corrupt, inkscape

When I import *.ai file to Inkscape, then colors become corrupt.
This means that these colors look like 4-bit indexed colors of early-era of 4bit color monitors.
  Here is a sample:
  ( http://landkey.net/sand/questions/inkscape-and-adobe/inkscape-has-different-colors.png ).

File and objects' paths apparently do import correctly.

I use Inscape 0.48.3.1 r9886 on Ubuntu 12.04.4.
  The same problem happens in GIMP 2.6 on Ubuntu 10.4
  When I am reading this *.ai file in Acrobat reader, colors are fine.
  When I am getting this file in PSD format in GIMP 2.6, then colors are fine, but I probably lose paths.

How to fix this problem for ai file?

I don't have AI to experiment. I receive files from remote team. If solution is found, i can make an advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way around a problem was to ask team members to save files as SVG from Adobe program.

Apparently, this is how to do this: http://www.quintaldesigns.com/articles/articles/svg-files-in-adobe-illustrator

This, however, did not solve problem completely.
It was already 3 months gone, but in my memory "Adobe" sometimes generated too huge svg-files, 5 Meg, or 25 Meg, and there was no way to import them into Inkscape.
( http://forums.adobe.com/message/6219387 )

The final solution was still to use PSD files in the interteam exchange.